# DSharpPlus Lavalink connection fails (server returned status code '404' when '101' was expected)

Tags: discord, dsharp+

I did create an Discord Music bot using DSharpPlus and made an Lavalink server for it.
But when I try to connect to the Lavalink server I get this error in my Bot console:

```
[2024-01-14 21:30:38 +01:00] [401 /LavalinkConn] [Crit ] Failed to connect to Lavalink, retrying in 7500 ms.
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): The server returned status code '404' when status code '101' was expected.
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ValidateResponse(HttpResponseMessage response, String secValue)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsync(Uri uri, HttpMessageInvoker invoker, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ClientWebSocketOptions options)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.ConnectAsyncCore(Uri uri, HttpMessageInvoker invoker, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at DSharpPlus.Net.WebSocket.WebSocketClient.ConnectAsync(Uri uri)
   at DSharpPlus.Lavalink.LavalinkNodeConnection.StartAsync()
```

I also get this in the Lavalink console:

```
2024-01-14T21:32:31.346+01:00  WARN 68551 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /
2024-01-14T21:32:31.347+01:00  INFO 68551 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] l.server.io.RequestLoggingFilter         : GET /
```

What does this error mean, and how do I fix it?

I allready did check if IP, Port, Passwort is correct, and tried rebuilding the Bot.

Comment: It may be possible that your Client machine does not support Websockets. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1098677/encountering-websocketexception-(0x80004005)-the-s)

Comment: There are a large number of reasons this can happen. I would start by confirming the server location and port are correct. If that's correct I would make sure that if you are hosting both lavalink and your bot on the same machine that they are both running and that lavalink is running before your bot is launched. 404 doesn't just mean it couldn't be found, it can also mean that the handshake failed and the server returned nothing at all but 404.

Comment: @ExplodatedFaces Sorry for the late response. 
Server Adress and Port is Corrrect, Lavalink and the bot are on the same Server and Lavalink was running before I started the Bot. But I still get this Error.
What can I do?